# Making body background fit the entire screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is likely a very easy question but I've tried all of the solutions posted and none of them seem to work for me.

I would simply like the gradient applied to my `<body>` HTML tag to always fit the screen properly. Whenever I view the browser in a smaller resolution such as this, and try to scroll over, the background appears as such.

Furthermore, if I turn off background-repeat, it just gets filled with white.

[image: Web page error]

Here is my base.html:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'assets/favicon.png' %}"/>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-social.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aladin" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block head-extras %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-white">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/home" class="navbar-brand">
          <h1 id="logo" class="nav-wel">Pomodoro</h1>
        </a>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <div class="status">Balance:&nbsp;{{ request.user.profile.coins }}<img class="coin-img" src="{% static 'assets/coin.png' %}" height="40px" width="auto"></div>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle welcome nav-wel" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="welcome">Welcome {{ user.get_username }}</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/shop">Shop</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/change-password">Change Password</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </nav>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/pomodoro.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
body {
  background: #c2e59c;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #c2e59c, #64b3f4);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #c2e59c, #64b3f4);
}
```

Comment: share your code please.

Comment: Should I post my entire stylesheet? @ehsan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your style in html tag instead :

```
html {
height: 100%;
background: #222d69;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;    
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
background: -moz-linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
background: -ms-linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
background: -o-linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
background: linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/qqdg9654/

Update :

Just add this one , your body background and background-color should be reset :

```
body{
   background:none;  
   background-color:none;
}
```

Comment: This is the effect of that: http://imgur.com/a/UcgjZ (with my gradient filled in of course)

Comment: It's getting better, but the gradient still won't extend: http://imgur.com/a/J4hU7

Comment: Adding "fixed" to the end of the gradient seemed to have done the trick!

Comment: Great, happy that it works for you finally! if my answer help you somehow, choose it as correct answer and give it up-vote ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to the top of your css file:

```
html, body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

There is also a css library called "normalize" that should take care of that for you.

Comment: Nitoivk, but you shouldn't provide units if the value is 0.

Comment: That's true, but I do it for compatibility reasons since some older browsers (*cough* IE *cough*) might only accept stuff like `margin:0;` half of the time. No joke but I once had a site that was displayed normally, then I reloaded it and the margin was there. Then I reloaded it and after a few tries it was normal again. @thewolff

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background: #c2e59c;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #c2e59c, #64b3f4);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #c2e59c, #64b3f4);
 background-size: fixed;
}
```

Try to use bg size and a min-height